# Closed formula for linear binomial identity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, problem-solving

I have the following identity:

\begin{equation}
m^4 = Z{m\choose 4}+Y{m\choose 3}+X{m\choose 2}+W{m\choose 1}
\end{equation}

I solved for the values and learned of the interpretation of W, X, Y, and Z in my last post:
[Combinatorial reasoning for linear binomial identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299658/combinatorial-reasoning-for-linear-binomial-identity)

Now, I am interested in using the above to find a closed form solution for:
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^4 \\
\end{equation}

I do not see how to get a closed form solution to the above sum. What steps can I take? I especially would like to use the work from [my last post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299658).

Thanks!

Comment: I was momentarily puzzled when I saw the words "closed form solution".  Then I realized you meant "closed-form expression".  One _solves_ a problem or _solves_ an equation.  One does not "solve" an expression.  One might _evaluate_ it (seeking a _value_, not a "solution"), or one might seek another expression for it.  But "solution" is not the right word here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the identity
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k-m}\binom{k-j}{m}\binom{j}{n}=\binom{k+1}{m+n+1}
$$
setting $m=0$ to get
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{j}{n}=\binom{k+1}{n+1}
$$
Then, once we have that
$$
m^4=24\binom{m}{4}+36\binom{m}{3}+14\binom{m}{2}+1\binom{m}{1}+0\binom{m}{0}
$$
we get that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^k m^4
&=24\binom{k+1}{5}+36\binom{k+1}{4}+14\binom{k+1}{3}+1\binom{k+1}{2}+0\binom{k+1}{1}\\
&=24\binom{k}{5}+60\binom{k}{4}+50\binom{k}{3}+15\binom{k}{2}+1\binom{k}{1}+0\binom{k}{0}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Awesome! The less general identity given in the second line is actually in my book and is used to show the sum of the first n integers when $n=1$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\sum_{m=1}^n\binom{m}{r}=\sum_{m=1}^n \left[\binom{m+1}{r+1}-\binom{m}{r+1}\right]$$
Now use the method of differences.

Answer (score 2):

If $r>1$:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r
\end{array}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-1\\
r
\end{array}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-1\\
r-1
\end{array}\right)=\\
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r
\end{array}\right)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r-1
\end{array}\right)=\\
=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r
\end{array}\right)-\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
r
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
r
\end{array}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r-1
\end{array}\right)-\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
r-1
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
r-1
\end{array}\right)=\\
=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r
\end{array}\right)-\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
r
\end{array}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r-1
\end{array}\right)-\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
r-1
\end{array}\right)=\\
=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r
\end{array}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r-1
\end{array}\right)-\left(\begin{array}{c}
n+1\\
r
\end{array}\right)
 $

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r
\end{array}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r
\end{array}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r-1
\end{array}\right)-\left(\begin{array}{c}
n+1\\
r
\end{array}\right)
  $

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r-1
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
n+1\\
r
\end{array}\right)
 $

Or $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
r
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
n+1\\
r+1
\end{array}\right) 
 $ (for $r>0$)

So, if $\begin{equation}
m^4 = Z{m\choose 4}+Y{m\choose 3}+X{m\choose 2}+W{m\choose 1}
\end{equation}$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{4}=X\left(\begin{array}{c}
n+1\\
5
\end{array}\right)+Y\left(\begin{array}{c}
n+1\\
4
\end{array}\right)+Z\left(\begin{array}{c}
n+1\\
3
\end{array}\right)+W\left(\begin{array}{c}
n+1\\
2
\end{array}\right)
 $

I remember it from book http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics, where Knuth and Co did the same thing what you want to do now.

Also I suggest related book $A=B$ (about summing of hypergeometric sums) which can be legally downloaded here - http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/Downld.html

---

So, if I got it right, then in general case

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{m}=\sum_{k=1}^{m}k!\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
m\\
k
\end{array}\right\} \left(\begin{array}{c}
n+1\\
k+1
\end{array}\right)
 $$

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus I hope you like general case formula. ;)

Comment: Your general case formula is correct.  A reference is p. 199 of Rosen, *Handbook of Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics*.